# Agora Unity SDK, I am not able to mute unmute user audio/video

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

(ANdriod) I am implementing Agora unity sdk in one of my game. I am able to initializae channel

```
if (mRtcEngine != null)
{
Debug.Log("Engine exists. Please unload it first!");
return;
}
// init engine
mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.GetEngine(AppId);
mRtcEngine.SetLogFilter(LOG_FILTER.DEBUG | LOG_FILTER.INFO | LOG_FILTER.WARNING | LOG_FILTER.ERROR | LOG_FILTER.CRITICAL);


// set callbacks (optional)
mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess = onJoinChannelSuccess;
mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined = onUserJoined;
mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline = onUserOffline;
mRtcEngine.SetChannelProfile(CHANNEL_PROFILE.CHANNEL_PROFILE_GAME);
// enable video
mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
// allow camera output callback
mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();

// join channel
mRtcEngine.OnLocalUserRegistered = OnLocalUserRegisteredHandler;
```

All this works fine and on a channel people can join and leave properly.

During conference where 4 users are there, I want to provide option to mute/unmute any player audio/video, so say user1 is seeing three user video u2,u3,u4 and now he want to mute audio/video of u4 so that on his device he won't be able to hear or see u4. How to achieve that.
I tried with IRTCEngine methods but no success like
MuteLocalAudioStream(), MuteLocalVideoStream() passing true false but nothing works and audio/video keep display with no effect.
Also for remote user i tried using
MuteRemoteAudioStream(),MuteRemoteVideoStream() passing the uid of user to mute but no error no success.

Can some please suggest me how to achieve it.  A little example would be fine if possible.

Thanks in advance.
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

MuteRemoteVideoStream() and MuteRemoteAudioStream() are the functions to use. I verified that they are doing they intended. Try again, observe it more closely and carefully. They work exactly for your case.

Comment: Please share the sample which is working for you. That would be help for me

Comment: It is probably better if you share your project so people can look at it.  The way you use the methods, to mute user u3, for instance:

mRtcEngine.MuteRemoteAudioStream(u3, true);

Comment: `agoraEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(true)` works in react native.check whether the same method exists with unity

Answer (score 0):

`agoraEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(true)` works in unity, please check is there any error before the line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34913748)